# Swapping a 12 speed 11-30t to 11-34t cassette Ultegra

Tags: road-bike, shimano, cassette, derailleur-rear, shimano-di2

I currently have a 12 speed 11-30t cassette on the back and 35x52 crank upfront.

If I change to a 11-34t cassette, do I need to adjust anything? (for example RD adjustment if so, what should I adjust. And can I use the current chain or I need a new one).

Answer (score 4):

You need to ensure your rear derailleur has the capacity and maximum cassette sprocket for the increased cassette - in this case you are going from a capacity of 36 to 40. I doubt any road derailleurs have that capacity, although you can often get away going a little over specification without too many problems.

If your chain is correct length for the 11-30, it will need to be longer for an 11.34. This should not be considered a problem as you should install a new chain when you install a new cassette.

You will probably need to adjust the B screw to move further out, so it clears the larger cogs.  H and L screws should be OK, but I would check them anyway.

https://www.parktool.com/en-us/blog/repair-help/rear-derailleur-adjustment is worth a read.

Comment: Actually, 12s Ultegra RDs have a rated capacity of 39t. For 52/36 chainrings with an 11-34 cassette, which is one of the stock configurations possible in Shimano 12s, the required capacity is actually 39, by my math. Same for the R8000 GS RDs. Times have actually changed quite a bit! Also, the 6800 RDs aren’t rated for this, but 11-34 cassettes didn’t exist when they were released, and I think they can informally handle this.

Comment: Regarding the B-screw adjustment: going from an 11-30t cassette to 11-34t calls for a change in the gap between the upper jockey wheel and the large cog to change from 14mm with the 30t to 6mm when using the 34t cog. The larger diameter of the 34t will cover much of this change, but B-screw adjustment will be necessary to achieve the 6mm gap.